# SkiaSharp set new rotation point at the centre of the canvas and Rotate around that point

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I'm never used SkiaSharp or dealt with SVG and rotation points in programming yet. I'm confused about how the matrix works; it looks very complex while researching. I know I can move my pivotX/Y point to the center to allow me to say I want to rotate an image 180 degrees and it would be 1:1 with all pixels.

**Note**: I did not create any of these SVGs, they are made by someone within the company.

I'm using Xamarin Community Toolkit to get the custom Popup. The SVG I draw is always drawn upside down. So I would like to rotate it 180 degrees but I'm not sure how to set the pivotX/Y at the center of either `StarPath` or the `Canvas center`.

Whole point of this question so I can learn how to manipulate Matrix in SkiaSharp and be able to make a method to Rotate my Path by specifying the `degrees` `width / 2` `height / 2`

Xamarin Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xct:Popup xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
           x:Class="uCue_Game.View.LostLifePopUp"
           xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
           xmlns:sksh="clr-namespace:SkiaSharp.Views.Forms;assembly=SkiaSharp.Views.Forms"
           Size="400, 400"
           Color="Transparent">

    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Black"
          Opacity="1">

        <sksh:SKCanvasView x:Name="canvasView"
                           PaintSurface="canvasView_PaintSurface"
                           HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                           VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                           HeightRequest="300"
                           Opacity="1"/>
        <Label Text="Wrong Answer" 
               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
               VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
               FontSize="15"
               TextColor="White"
               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
               VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
               Opacity="1"/>
    </StackLayout>
</xct:Popup>
```

C# Code

```
public partial class LostLifePopUp : Popup
{
    SKPath StarPath = SKPath.ParseSvgPathData("M492" +
    " 348 c16 -18 47 -67 69 -110 38 -76 40 -78 77 -78 55 -1 156 -24 186 -43 42" +
    " -28 34 -61 -27 -120 -29 -29 -70 -63 -90 -77 -24 -16 -35 -30 -31 -40 18 -48" +
    " 44 -170 44 -211 0 -44 -3 -49 -25 -55 -31 -8 -144 27 -209 64 l-47 27 -97 -47" +
    " c-102 -50 -157 -65 -181 -49 -20 13 -16 97 9 195 l20 79 -58 61 c-69 73 -102" +
    " 118 -102 141 0 22 66 50 177 75 l90 21 22 53 c12 29 35 74 51 100 38 59 76 63" +
    " 122 14z");

    SKPath StarFill = SKPath.ParseSvgPathData("M487" +
    " 363 c21 -24 58 -71 83 -105 32 -46 51 -64 74 -69 65 -14 201 -56 213 -65 28" +
    " -23 2 -34 -85 -35 -109 -1 -229 -31 -336 -85 -136 -69 -223 -82 -298 -43 -32" +
    " 17 -98 73 -98 84 0 4 10 18 23 32 12 14 32 37 44 51 12 15 35 29 50 33 15 4" +
    " 49 15 75 26 38 16 51 29 76 76 50 94 89 142 116 142 15 0 38 -16 63 -42z");

    SKPath StarShine = SKPath.ParseSvgPathData(
        "M0 1215 m0 -1215 m1260 0 m1260 0 m0 1215 m0 1215 m-1260 0 m-1260 0 m0" +
        " -1215z m1395 838 c35 -35 95 -164 95 -204 0 -55 -64 -92" +
        " -117 -69 -56 25 -68 54 -68 166 0 105 10 134 45 134 9 0 30 -12 45 -27z");

    SKPaint StrokeRed = new SKPaint
    {
        Style = SKPaintStyle.StrokeAndFill,
        Color = SKColors.Red,
        StrokeWidth = 5,
        StrokeCap = SKStrokeCap.Round,
        StrokeJoin = SKStrokeJoin.Round
    };

    SKPaint FillYellow = new SKPaint
    {
        Style = SKPaintStyle.Fill,
        Color = SKColors.Yellow,
        StrokeWidth = 5,
        StrokeCap = SKStrokeCap.Round,
        StrokeJoin = SKStrokeJoin.Round
    };

    SKPaint GoldShine = new SKPaint
    {
        Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke,
        Color = SKColors.Green,
        StrokeWidth = 40,
        StrokeCap = SKStrokeCap.Round,
        StrokeJoin = SKStrokeJoin.Round
    };

    public LostLifePopUp()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void canvasView_PaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
    {
        SKRect bounds;
        StarPath.GetBounds(out bounds);

        var surface = e.Surface;
        var surfaceWidth = e.RawInfo.Width;
        var surfaceHeight = e.RawInfo.Height;

        var canvas = surface.Canvas;

        canvas.Flush();
        canvas.Clear();

        var rot = SKMatrix.CreateRotationDegrees(37, surfaceWidth / 2 - 50, surfaceHeight / 2);
        canvas.SetMatrix(rot);

        canvas.Translate(surfaceWidth / 2, surfaceHeight / 2);
        canvas.Scale(0.9f * Math.Min(surfaceWidth / bounds.Width,
                                    surfaceHeight / bounds.Height));
        canvas.Translate(-bounds.MidX, -bounds.MidY);

        canvas.DrawPath(StarShine, GoldShine);
        canvas.DrawPath(StarPath, StrokeRed);
        canvas.DrawPath(StarFill, FillYellow);
    }
}
```

**Current Updated Code** - I'm running out of time so I cannot play around anymore with this `SkiaSharp` for now. I will be working on 2nd version of this game which is a more complex version so I will come back to this as soon as I get onto that. I'm really not happy with `SKMatrix.PostConcat` makes the method `obsolete` and inaccessible from anywhere. I have 2 states for my star when someone loses a level and I had to take a very wrong approach to achieve it but it's something for later to fix. Also if the canvas size changes the whole drawing goes to hell, it's all other the place.

```
private void canvasView_PaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
{
    SKRect bounds;
    StarPath.GetBounds(out bounds);

    var surface = e.Surface;
    var surfaceWidth = e.RawInfo.Width;
    var surfaceHeight = e.RawInfo.Height;

    var canvas = surface.Canvas;

    var result = SKMatrix.CreateIdentity();
    var translate = SKMatrix.CreateTranslation(-surfaceWidth / 2, -surfaceHeight / 2);
    var rotate = SKMatrix.CreateRotationDegrees(180);
    var translate2 = SKMatrix.CreateTranslation(surfaceWidth * 2, surfaceHeight);
    SKMatrix.PostConcat(ref result, translate);
    SKMatrix.PostConcat(ref result, rotate);
    SKMatrix.PostConcat(ref result, translate2);
    StarPath.Transform(result);
    StarFill.Transform(result);

    canvas.Scale(0.8f * Math.Min(surfaceWidth / bounds.Width, surfaceHeight / bounds.Height));

    canvas.DrawPath(StarPath, WhiteOutline);
    canvas.DrawPath(StarPath, Yellow);
    canvas.DrawPath(StarFill, Shine);

    if (DrawMain == true)
    {
        canvas.Scale(0.7f * Math.Min(surfaceWidth / bounds.Width, surfaceHeight / bounds.Height));
        translate2 = SKMatrix.CreateTranslation(surfaceWidth * 2.5f, surfaceHeight * 2);
        SKMatrix.PostConcat(ref result, translate2);
        StarShine.Transform(result);
        canvas.DrawPath(StarShine, White);
    }
            
    if (DrawSecond == true)
    {
        canvas.DrawPath(StarPath, WhiteOutline);
    }
}
```

This is what is looks like currently. I cant see the Shine nor does the fill actually fill the entire star... Right Image is what it should look like.

[image][image]

Comment: I haven't looked at your matrix transforms in detail, but often the problem is finding the correct **order** in which to do the transforms. This takes some trial and error. Its easiest to get correct if you experiment with the transforms "one at a time". Start with JUST the rotation plus image, with nothing else in the canvas. You may need to rotate by small amounts first, to see exactly what it is doing. Is it rotating around one corner, or perhaps the middle of one edge? Next, experiment with translation and rotation. Try both ways: what happens with translation first? with rotation first.

Comment: ... scale is the **last** one to add in. Because how that interacts with rotation and translation is often non-obvious. Hopefully you can add it either at the beginning or at the end [once you have rotation + translation doing what you want], and ONE of those places will work.

Answer (score 1):

============**update answer**======

From my point of view, you could change the StarPath to draw star at the center.

I make this on a 300 X 300 canvasview

```
    SKPath StarPath = SKPath.ParseSvgPathData("m 492" +
    " 805.6 c 16 -18 47 -67 69 -110 c 38 -76 40 -78 77 -78 c 55 -1 156 -24 186 -43" +
    " c 42 -28 34 -61 -27 -120 c -29 -29 -70 -63 -90 -77 c -24 -16 -35 -30 -31 -40" +
    "  c 18 -48 44 -170 44 -211 c 0 -44 -3 -49 -25 -55 c -31 -8 -144 27 -209 64" +
    "  l -47 27 l -97 -47 c -102 -50 -157 -65 -181 -49 c -20 13 -16 97 9 195 l 20 79" +
    "  l -58 61 c -69 73 -102 118 -102 141 c 0 22 66 50 177 75 l 90 21 l 22 53 c 12 29" +
    "  35 74 51 100 c 38 59 76 63 122 14 z");
```

It draws the star at the center. I use iphone13 simulator which has a high resolution of @3x scale factor.

============**Origin answer**

Thanks for @ThisQRequiresASpecialist's comment. I found that the order of transform is quite important. If you rotate the canvas, the coordinate system also rotate. That means if you rotate 90 degree, x-axis changes to y-axis, and y-axis changes to x-axis which cause troubles for the later translation. So translation first and then rotate could be better.

In your case, to rotate 180 degree and translate to the center, just try the following code:

```
void canvasView_PaintSurface(System.Object sender, SkiaSharp.Views.Forms.SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
{   
    SKImageInfo info = e.Info;
    SKRect bounds;           
    var surface = e.Surface;           
    var surfaceWidth = info.Width;
    var surfaceHeight = info.Height;     
    StarPath.GetTightBounds(out bounds);
    
    canvas.Translate(surfaceWidth/2 - bounds.MidX,  (surfaceHeight / 2 - bounds.MidY)); // Translate to the center
    canvas.RotateDegrees(180, bounds.MidX, bounds.MidY); // rotate 180
```

...
}

=======**Update here**=======

@ThisQRequiresASpecialist's comment also show a new method using Matrix. I also made a demo and it worked.

```
var result = SKMatrix.CreateIdentity();
var rotate = SKMatrix.CreateRotationDegrees(180, bounds.MidX, bounds.MidY);
var translate = SKMatrix.CreateTranslation(surfaceWidth / 2 - bounds.MidX, -(surfaceHeight / 2 - bounds.MidY));
SKMatrix.PostConcat(ref result, translate);
SKMatrix.PostConcat(ref result, rotate);           
StarPath.Transform(result);
canvas.DrawPath(StarPath, StrokeRed);
```

For more information, you could refer to [The Rotate Transform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/transforms/rotate)

Hope my answer could help you.

Comment: I've tried your code in a new Xamarin Forms app so I can have Minimal Reprodusable Code. Works perfectly for 180degrees but if I want to rotate it 90degrees it's off the screen. My perfect example of what I would like is this [article](https://trailheadtechnology.com/rotate-everything-with-skiasharp-and-xamarin/#:~:text=Rotation%20and%20SkiaSharp) but I'm struggling to understand the math. You'll see the square that is rotating at the center of itself. That's what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: `canvas.RotateDegrees(180, bounds.MidX, bounds.MidY);` just make it rotate at the center.  I also update my answer. Please have a look.

Comment: I really appreciate your answers, but I got the same result by following the code in the article post. What I realized is that I need to change my point of `origin` to be the center of the `star`. My goal is to achieve the same thing he got in the example `square 3` the rotating around the center of itself. This is much harder then I thought. All your answer do get the result of 180degree rotation but its point origin is either bottom right corner or top right corner and I need it to be exactly in middle of the canvas.

Comment: Did you mean that you want to set the center of the star to (0,0)? I'm not sure if it could be realized as xamarin is top-left based.

Comment: I think that's what I mean. So the canvas has a size let's say `300x300` point of origin would be `0, 0` to left. I will draw my star in the middle of the canvas and set the new point of origin to `150, 150` exact middle. That would allow me to rotate the canvas or star around itself rather than top left. Doesn that make sense? I'm so confused with this. Sorry if I'm miss leading.

Comment: I think the StarPath has to be changed as the coordinate value is based on xamarin top-left.

Comment: I have updated a new StarPath which could make the star center of the v300x300 view.

Comment: I really do appreciate your time trying to help me. This is definitely not the solution, changing the `SVG` path is very inefficient from the development side of view. My canvas size always changes. I have to make sure this app works on all phone sizes and screens, if I have to change a path for each size difference I will be here for another couple of weeks. Must be something we're both overlooking here. Must be a way to just always get the `SVG` to sit right in the center of the canvas no matter the size. I gave you an Upvote for effort but I cant accept it as an answer.

Comment: In my opinion, using matrix essentially is the same as to make some translation or rotation. I mean only use matrix may not be a good way to place SVG in the center.

Comment: Is there any other way to do what I need to do? SVGs I nice as they scale pixel perfect with canvas. But that's only when the code is correct to get them to be in the center.

Comment: I haven't find a way to what you need till now. maybe more research should be done. I will update my answer if a solution is found.